# How to use Netcipher with Retrofit in android?

Tags: android, encryption, retrofit

Netcipher is an Android Library Project that provides multiple means to improve network security in mobile applications. The “Onion” name refers to not only the Onion Routing concept used by Tor (which provides anonymity and resistance to traffic surveillance), but also the idea of multiple layers of security that any application should utilize.

More specifically this library provides:

```
1. Stronger Sockets: Through support for the right cipher suites, pinning and more, we ensure your encrypted connections are as strong as possible.
2. Proxied Connection Support: HTTP and SOCKS proxy connection support for HTTP and HTTP/S traffic through specific configuration of the Apache HTTPClient library
```

https://guardianproject.info/code/netcipher/

Comment: What you have tried? Have you found some intersection point between these two, where you can combine them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to implement your own `Client` that will execute Retrofit request on Netcipher http client.

1. Translate `Request` to appropriate Netcipher request (copy http method, headers, body)
2. Execute the translated request on Netcipher http client
3. Obtain response and translated it to retrofit `Response` (copy http status code, response, headers)
4. Return response to be deserialized to type.

Pass your `Client` to `RestAdapter.Builder`.

Done.

```
public class NetcipherClient implements Client{
  private Context mContext;
  public NetcipherClient(Context context){
      mContext = context;
      //As far as I could see from the sample, Netcipher seems to be dependant on application `Context`.

  }
  @Override
    public retrofit.client.Response execute(retrofit.client.Request request) throws IOException {
        //Set up configuration for Netcipher (proxy, timeout etc)
        // Translate Request to Netcipher request 
        // Execute and obtain the response
        // Build Response from response
        return response;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

We've recently implemented support for OkHTTP in NetCipher so it should be easy to add Tor support to Retrofit via OkHTTP.  Here's how:

```
compile 'info.guardianproject.netcipher:netcipher-okhttp3:2.0.0-alpha1'
```

The core of this is just running the method to set things up:

```
  StrongOkHttpClientBuilder
    .forMaxSecurity(this)
    .withTorValidation()
    .build(this);
```

See the included [sample-okhttp3](https://github.com/guardianproject/NetCipher/blob/master/sample-okhttp3) project for a full example, which is part of the git repo https://github.com/guardianproject/NetCipher

Answer (score 2):

Except Tor-like routing [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) also have the certificate pinning ability & proxy support. And it works with Retrofit out-of-the-box! So, if Tor-like functions are not so important for you, I recommend to utilize OkHttp's awesomeness. Otherwise, answer by @NikolaDespotoski is your perfect choice.